# Jquery ScrollTop experiencing strange functionality

Tags: jquery, html, css, razor

I'm experiencing functionality in one div that has an overflow set to auto, and another not having any functionality at all. Since one div contains a Razor WebGrid and the other is for testing purposes, which just contains a bit of text be the issue? The scroll event nor the scrollTop method are called for pre-transmissiongrid.

Code snippets

Razor Div:

```
<div id="pre-transmissiongrid">
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-striped table-bordered"
        @*... contents *@
       )
</div>
```

Test Div:

```
<div id="scrollTest" style="height : 100px; overflow : auto;">
1 - Long Div Scrolling text <br />
2 - Long Div Scrolling text <br />
3 - Long Div Scrolling text <br />
4 - Long Div Scrolling text <br />
5 - Long Div Scrolling text <br />
6 - Long Div Scrolling text <br />
7 - Long Div Scrolling text <br />
8 - Long Div Scrolling text <br />
9 - Long Div Scrolling text <br />
10 - Long Div Scrolling text <br />
11 - Long Div Scrolling text <br />
12 - Long Div Scrolling text <br />
13 - Long Div Scrolling text <br />
14 - Long Div Scrolling text <br />
15 - Long Div Scrolling text <br />
16 - Long Div Scrolling text <br />
17 - Long Div Scrolling text <br />
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="test()">scroll down</button>
```

Javascript for both:

```
function test() {
    $('#scrollTest').scrollTop(200);
    $('#pre-transmissiongrid').scrollTop(200);
}
$("#scrollTest").scroll(function () {
    alert("test");
});
$("#pre-transmissiongrid").scroll(function () {
    alert("grid");
});
```

Comment: So what's the strangeness, and what's the question ?

Comment: I modified my question above.

Comment: And you've made sure that you can actually get the element with the selector `$('#pre-transmissiongrid')` and that the scrollbar is in fact attached to that element

Comment: Hmm.. that makes sense. I have my overflow set like this,
#pre-transmission tbody{
    overflow-y: auto;
}
I should take that into account?